# Twisted connections timeout under heavy load

Tags: django, sockets, ubuntu, network-programming, twisted

We have a Django web app that serves a moderate number of users, running on an Ubuntu machine with 8 cores and at least 32GB RAM. We have no problems with users connecting via their browser. However, on the backend (on the same server) we are also running a twisted server. The Django webapp tries to connect to our twisted server, but after about 1100-1200 such connections (including a bunch of persistent connections to other devices on the backend), all the connections start to timeout. Our twisted server worked fine under low load but now the server seems to be unable to handle any new connections from Django. All connections time out. We do not see anything obviously wrong with our code (which we have been working on for a couple of years now so it should be pretty stable). We have already set our soft and hard ulimits in /etc/security/limits.conf to 50000/65000 and we have upped somaxconn to 65536. The print of limits for our twisted process is listed below. The total number of files across the tope 25 processes is just over 5000. Unfortunately we still cannot get more than roughly 1100-1200 simultaneous connections to our twisted server. What things should we look at to make our twisted connections start connecting again? Are there other sysctl or other Ubuntu Linux parameters that we need to change? Are there twisted parameters we need to change?

```
Limit                     Soft Limit           Hard Limit           Units
Max cpu time              unlimited            unlimited            seconds
Max file size             unlimited            unlimited            bytes
Max data size             unlimited            unlimited            bytes
Max stack size            8388608              unlimited            bytes
Max core file size        0                    unlimited            bytes
Max resident set          unlimited            unlimited            bytes
Max processes             465901               465901               processes
Max open files            50000                65000                files
Max locked memory         65536                65536                bytes
Max address space         unlimited            unlimited            bytes
Max file locks            unlimited            unlimited            locks
Max pending signals       465901               465901               signals
Max msgqueue size         819200               819200               bytes
Max nice priority         0                    0
Max realtime priority     0                    0
Max realtime timeout      unlimited            unlimited            us
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twisted is a thin shell around your application.  When there is a performance problem, almost always, the problem is somewhere inside the application and not in Twisted.  So there is no general answer to this question.

That said, there are a couple of investigation techniques you could use.  Is your Twisted process consuming 100% CPU?  If so, then you are going to need to split it up into multiple processes somehow (using `spawnProcess`, `sendFileDescriptor` and `adoptStreamPort` to allow I/O to be done in subprocesses).  If not, then your problem is probably some inadvertent blocking I/O preventing the reactor from servicing requests: you might use something like [`twisted_hang`](https://github.com/ggreer/twisted_hang) to diagnose hot-spots where the reactor is getting "stuck".

There's also the possibility that the problem could be on Django's side of the connection.  However, with no information about how Django is making those connections, there's little more I can even guess.

Comment: The machine (VM actually) has 8 cores. When I run htop it shows that the average load on each core is around 20-30%. The listing of processes in htop shows that one process always uses around 150% CPU. The load average is  1.48, 1.50, 1.40. Is this load spread over all cores or does this load mean I need to split up the process into multiple processes?

Comment: We are also logging various things and the log files are showing that the reactor does not hang. When the load reduces, everything works fine but when more clients connect, socket connections start timing out. Any other ideas?

Comment: As for how Django is making the connections, it is making them using the python telnetlib module.

Comment: We also have other embedded devices that are connecting to the problem twisted server. These embedded devices use a twisted SSLClient to connect and they are having connection problems too. So it isn't a Django problem.

Comment: Anyone have any ideas? We're kinda stuck here.

Comment: When you say "one process" is using 150% CPU, do you mean your Twisted process is using 150% CPU?  The only interesting number for the purposes of this discussion is whether the Twisted service you are having connection issues with is maxed out.  Is it just one process, or is it something with a load-balancer already in front of it?

Comment: No this is just one python process. We figure out that this one process was in fact the bottleneck - it is obvious now since one python process is not split across multiple cores, it itself is using 140% CPU. We are splitting up that process into multiple processes and that should fix the problem. Thanks.

Comment: If you don't mind me asking, what strategy are you using to split it up? Is it straightforward or is it difficult?

Comment: Turns out it was fairly easy to split up. We just had to create a new instance of the service that listens on a different port. Our VM had 12 cores so we had the processor capability to split it up easily.